# How to run Mapbox Vector Tile Mini Server?

Tags: vector, tiles, mapbox, mbtiles, vector-tiles

I am trying to make an offline map for the vector tiles that I've exported from Mapbox Studio (mbtiles). I found this :

https://github.com/BergWerkGIS/mini-server

I have it downloaded on my desktop and it works online, but I can't get it to work offline. I just want to be able to have my vector tiles(mbtiles) to be displayed on the browser offline.

Comment: Did you figure this out? How did you export mbtiles from mapbox studio - I can only export a tm2z package